# Random delays using Volley request

Tags: android, android-volley, nanohttpd

I'm using a `Volley singleton` to send POST messages to a `NanoHTTPD` server made in java. The messages are short and the process time is fast, and there are no more than 1 message at the same time.

The problem is that randomly there are some delays in the queue to process the request, generating loading times of 3-4 seconds. The most common case is the first message(this is no problem, i guess is making some instances) or when I wait more than 5-10 seconds after any message. But if I send, for example 100 POST messages with 1 second delay between there is no problem.

I've checked the server and there is no request generated, so the problem is in the client side.

In those cases, the *logcat* show this:

> D/Volley: [839] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for
>   request=<[ ] http://192.168.2.8:8765 0x355fcdd NORMAL 1>
>   [lifetime=4768], [size=115], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]

Doing some google **logSlowRequests** means just that... the request took time to process in the client side.

Another solution to try is increasing the *threadPoolSize* but this didn't work. Always the first request takes a lot of time.

This is the singleton Code:

```
public class VolleySingleton {

    private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private DiskBasedCache cache;
    private BasicNetwork network;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // Instantiate the cache
            cache = new DiskBasedCache(mCtx.getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
            // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
            network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network, 20);
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    /**
     * @param req
     * @param <T>
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a more deep debug and the problem was the server:

```
    this.remoteHostname = !inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && !inetAddress.isAnyLocalAddress()?inetAddress.getHostName().toString():"localhost";
```

This generate a DNS lookup that take several seconds.

There is an issue already uploaded in the library github project:

https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/issues/396